# python htmlparser '&' character

Tags: python, html-parsing

`HTMLParser` module of `python` has a problem while parsing data which has `&` character. The html code below is taken from [here](http://haberciniz.biz/fenerbahce-tv-yayin-akisi-27-subat-2014-2650798h.htm)

`<td style="text-align: center; color:#c00;">15:30</td><td>Haber</td><td>Haber &      Aktüalite</td>`

The parser code is:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class HTMLParser_haberciniz(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.inlink = False

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'td':
            self.inlink = True

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == 'td':
            self.inlink = False

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.inlink :
            print data
```

Problem is that it parses all `Haber`, `&`, `Aktüalite` as different token which actually should be `Haber & Aktüalite` .

Comment: `&` in html should be encoded as an entity ( `&amp;` ) for the obvious reason that `&` syntactically encodes the beginning of a html entity ( named character outside the range of common 8bit-charsets ) and therefore needs escaping. most browsers' parsers detect the use of `&` in a context that suggests the use as literal char and auto-correct, so html authors tend to be a bit sloppy ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many XML parsers are not guaranteed to call "data" callback in one go, even for consecutive text fragments. It is probably also the case with HTMLParser. So you'd better not rely on it. You can append data to some internal buffer, and then process it only when any other kind of event happens.

And yes, as collapsar said, HTML is also technically invalid, though the parser seems to parse it in reasonable way.